# Mongodb regex search but doesn't return all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to search a string in my collection below

```
      {
        question: "What is your least favorite thing about living in the USA?",
        description: "aaaa"
    },
    {
        question: "What is the saddest thing a casino dealer has seen at their table?",
        description: "bbbb"
    }
```

I was able to do so by using

```
db.questions.aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { question_title: { $regex: 'what', $options: "i" } }
   ]
)
```

and I received both documents. However, when I use keyword

```
'what USA'
```

I don't receive any result. My expected result is

```
"What is your least favorite thing about living in the USA?"
```

Can you suggest me a regex that I can use so that I will get a result if any of my keywords match with question document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
db.questions.aggregate([
    { $match: { question: { $regex: '(?i)(:s|usa|what)', $options: "i" } } }
])
```

This is case insensitive `(?i)` match which currently looks for either `usa` or `what`

You can [play with the regEx more here](https://regex101.com/r/9acLqP/1)

Comment: For the keyword, let say I have a value const keyword = 'test' in nodeJS, can I put in like this $regex: '(?i)(:s|keyword|)' because keyword is an input from user

Comment: yes that is the idea ... you would end up with `{ $regex: '(?i)(:s|test)', $options: "i" }`

Comment: In NodeJS, I can't seem to make it work with an input from user. It does work if I put $regex: '(?i)(:s|usa|what)' but if I put in keyword variable such as var keyword = userInput and $regex: '(?i)(:s|userInput)', mongoDB doesnt recognize. Do you know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: `$regex: '(?i)(:s|' + userInput + ')'` or if you can use template literal `$regex: (?i)(:s|${userInput})`. You need to basically concat the strings parts and the variable

Comment: Got it! Thank so much!

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic regex :

1.This regex Not match exact words return result for 'ua what':

```
var searchString = 'usa what';
    var regexStr = '(?i)(:s|' + searchString.split(' ').join('|')+')';
    db.getCollection('searchQuestion').aggregate(
       [
         { $match: { question: { $regex: regexStr, $options: "i" } } },

       ]
    );
```

2.For exact match words.

Example :

```
var searchStringg = 'usa what';
 var regexStrr = '\\b' + searchStringg.split(' ').join('\\b|\\b')+'\\b';
db.getCollection('searchQuestion').aggregate(
   [
     { $match: { question: { $regex: regexStrr, $options: "i" } } },

   ]
)
```

Comment: Since we have $options: "i" , do we still need (?i)